Showing password while pressing down a button
At the moment I'm creating an app with c# for my school project and I'm having a problem on the password.
When the app loads the LOGIN form, the password is hiden with this command:
private void login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.loginTableAdapter.Fill(this.apprugbyDataSet.Login);
    this.Size = new Size(360, 630);

    txtPass.PasswordChar = '*';
}

What do I need to do to show the password WHILE clicking on the button and hidding it again when released?
I've tried with the MouseUp and the MouseDown.

Note I changed names of controls.
Add the following class to your project which contains a language extension to toggle password visibility.
public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static void ToggleShow(this TextBox sender, bool show = true)
    {
        sender.PasswordChar = show ? '\0' : '\u25CF';
    }
}

To implement

In form shown event add the following passwordTextBox.ToggleShow(false); where passwordTextBox is the TextBox to show/hide the password. This will hide the password.
Add two events for the button to toggle password, MouseDown and MouseUp by selecting the button, go to properties than the events and double click on each of the two events.

Insert the following code.
private void revealPasswordButton_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    passwordTextBox.ToggleShow();
}

private void revealPasswordButton_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    passwordTextBox.ToggleShow(false);
}

